# execute sql query and loop through result set in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, i have the following function in one of my controller page.

```
def tree
@jstree = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select sequence, depth, node, imageid, range from.....several joins")
end
```

I now want to loop through the resultset and display the sequence only in my view page `tree.html.erb`. I tried the following code, it does not seem to work.

```
<% @jstree.each do |tree| %>
<%= tree.sequence %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the error message: `undefined method 'sequence' for #<Array:0x60e0088>`.

Is there a way of looping through the result set of the sql query executed and displaying each column value?

Many many thanks for all suggestion provided :)

Comment: Which version of rails and what database adapter are you using?

Comment: am using rails 2.3.5 and mysql adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because what you get in `@jstree` is a raw DB adapter result. If you want to query for some objects by issuing raw SQL queries then use `find_by_sql`. Example:

```
Client.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM clients INNER JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id ORDER clients.created_at desc")
```

Comment: What is `Client` in this case?

Comment: @Catfish your model.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping the same syntax as the OP

```
<% @jstree.each do |tree| %>
<%= tree[0] %>
<% end %>
```

would accomplish what you were looking for.